# What is an expression in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I read that there are no statements, just expressions in Haskell. I think an expression is something that evaluates (reduces) to a value. `1 + 1` is an expression, right? It reduces to `2`, but how about a number alone: `8`?
Is that `8` alone also considered to be an expression? An expression that doesn't reduce any further? I would be grateful for any clarification.

Comment: Probably. Usually, we define the grammar of programming languages to be as simple as possible. `8` should be an expression because it should work in all the same places that `(1 + 1)` does. You should verify with a Haskell grammar specification.

Comment: An expression is any piece of code that results in a value (e.g. `8` or `1+1` or `\x -> x*2`). This is as opposed to a *statement*, which does not result in a value, and is instead executed purely for its side effects (like Java `System.out.println("Hello");`). Since Haskell is pure and has no side effects, it necessarily can't have statements. You technically don't "execute" anything, you just compose actions into a single value that represents your whole program (and return it from `main`). It sounds really weird in theory, but it's practical, flexible and familiar in practice.

Comment: That's sorta a false dichotomy, or maybe a true one that's not very useful. There is lots of Haskell code that cannot be evaluated to a value. For example: import statements, top-level definitions, language pragmas. You could make a similar argument about statements in do-blocks: such a statement is *part of* an expression, but itself is not an expression. Are these all therefore statements, or are they something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I read that there are no statements, just expressions in Haskell.

To elaborate on @amalloy's comments about there being more than expressions in Haskell: You normally make the distinction between statements and expressions in imperative languages because you have something like `x = 2 + 2;` with the `x = ...;` part being a statement and the `2 + 2` part being an expression.

The body of a Haskell function is always one single expression (although with `where` you can split that one expression apart for convenience), and this is the main distinction that drives the question. So if you want to "do more than one thing", which is an imperative notion of a function being able to change global state, you solve this with monads, like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main (main) where
import Web.Scotty

main :: IO ()
main = scotty 3000 $
  get "/:who" $ do
    who <- param "who"
    text ("Beam " <> who <> " up, Scotty!")
```

Here, `main`'s body (a monadic action, not a function) is a single expression, `scotty 3000 (...)`. While the linebreak after `scotty 3000 $` doesn't carry meaning and only makes the code look nicer, the linebreak in the `do` block actually reduces multiple actions into one expression via syntactic sugar. So while it may seem that this event handler does two things things: (1) `param "who"`, (2) `text (...)`, it is still one expression equivalent to this:

```
main =
  scotty 3000 (get "/:who" (param "who" >>= (\who -> text ("Beam " <> who <> " up, Scotty!"))))
```

with `>>=` being the [invisible operator](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation) between the `do`-block lines. When expressions begin to grow, this becomes very inconvenient, so you split parts of them into sub-expressions and give those names, e.g. like:

```
main = scotty 3000 handler
  where
    handler = do
      get "/:who" getWho
      post "/" postWho

    getWho = do
      ...

    postWho = do
      ...
```

But it is essentially equivalent to one big expression.

This is the point where some people think they should make their own web-framework. :-D

There are many things in the language beyond function bodies that are not expressions; in the example above, the following are not expressions:

- `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` (a [language pragma](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch12.html))
- `module Main (main) where` (a [module, export list](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html))
- `import Web.Scotty` (an [import declaration](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-980005))
- `main :: IO ()` (a [type signature](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html))
- `main =` (a [top declaration](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#dx11-98006), or a [value binding](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-620004))

Of these, I think `import Web.Scotty` could be called a kind of statement, since grammatically it's in imperative form, but if we're going to be imprecise, I'd prefer to call them all *declarations*.

More interestingly, in Haskell you have both an expression language at the value level *and* one at the type level. So `IO ()` isn't a *value expression*, but it's a *type expression*. If you had the ability to mix those two expression languages up, you'd have [dependent types](https://medium.com/background-thread/the-future-of-programming-is-dependent-types-programming-word-of-the-day-fcd5f2634878).

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, `1 + 1` is an expression. Yes, `8` is an expression. Whether `8` reduces further is a slightly complicated question, just because of a strange detail of Haskell: numbers are polymorphic. At the usual types like `Int` and `Double`, `8` does not reduce meaningfully; but one could add a user-made instance where `8` could reduce further.

...but those are sort of annoying language-lawyer-y quibbles. In the big picture, everything you said is essentially right.